# A clarification regarding mathematical induction.

Tags: induction, education

Please forgive me if this has already been asked(my initial searches didn't find anything close enough).

I am studying Mathematical Induction and in the Inductive Step when we Assume Statement True for Nth Element and prove it holds for (N+1)th Element, hence it holds for Entire Set<< EXACTLY here

Does this mean that we have just proven that the statement holds NOT ONLY for a Discreet Element(0) BUT ALSO for a PAIR of Arbitrary Elements bound by Successor Relation and since Starting from 0 we can make pairs of ALL Elements of a Set of Natural Numbers that are bound by Successor Relation, hence it holds for Entire Set...

Another add on question is; Can Induction be applied to prove theorems in ALL kinds of sets or there is a restriction like it can ONLY be applied on ordered sets, where elements of the set are in some kind of relationship with one another?

I am self-taught so my knowledge level is around high school I guess...

[EDIT:] 
It seems to me that since the inductive step proves that the statement holds for **A** PAIR of Consecutive Elements of the set AND since every consecutive pair has the EXACTLY same relationship with one another, the statement holds for ENTIRE SET. It seems to me that the Definition of the elements(with relations with one another) of the set plays a huge role in making Induction a valid proof. As mentioned by @DavidDiaz in comments that "Induction is for strictly well ordered set".

Comment: Looks like you got the idea in general, you have base element that the statement true about him, and have an arbitrary elements $n$, and $n+1$ which can implied by its previous one (ore several). Notice that the $n$, $n+1$ required the order, so for the following question, the set must have full relation (every couple of elements in a relation)+there is a smallest element (element that always less or equal to all others elements in the set)

Comment: Induction is strictly for well ordered sets that can be put into correspondence with some subset of the natural numbers. If you wanted to prove something about a set of colors, induction wouldn't work.

Comment: @friedvir it seems as if Induction is somehow saying that the Statement not only holds for a Discreet Element of the Set but ALSO holds true for a "Relation" between the Elements of the set, in this case the Successor Relation. Although it's quite obvious I cannot fill a Relation for "n" in n(n+1)/2, but somehow it feels that way. Or am I Completely wrong.

Comment: @DavidDiaz Thanks, I wanted someone to confirm that("Induction is strictly for..."). I had the inkling but my google searches didn't provide me the answer.

Comment: @Ashish o.k, i just ment that sometimes the assumption is not on the n'th element but all over the smaller than the (n+1)'th ones. For example, if you want to show that all natural numbers are primes or combined by multiplication of primes, assuming the n'th alone won't be helpful